# impossible to send email in application deployed on Glassfish

Tags: java, glassfish, classcastexception, jakarta-mail

I've spent literally two days with this, googled it everywhere and still couldnt solve it, let's see if someone finds what I'm doing wrong:

I've defined a javaMail Session in Glassfish, with all the parameters needed to communicate with a mail server (host, user, pass, port, etc..). I deploy an application that looks up that Session using jndi and tries to send an email. The code is:

```
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
Session session = (Session) ctx.lookup("mail/javaMailSession");

Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);  
msg.setSubject("test");  
msg.setRecipient(RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("zzz@yyy.com", "zzz"));    
msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("jjjj@kkkk.com", "hhh"));  
BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();  
messageBodyPart.setText("this is a test email");

Transport.send(msg);
```

Now if I deploy my app without the mail.jar dependency, when the class that contains this code is loaded I get a

`ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.Message, meaning mail.jar is not in the classpath.`

If I place mail.jar into domain/lib folder or just add a classpath entry into my app's manifest including the location of mail.jar, I no longer have the `ClassNotFoundException`, but when the lookup is executed and I retrieve the Session, I get the weirdest

```
ClassCastException: javax.mail.Session cannot be cast to javax.mail.Session.
```

This would mean that I have two versions of mail.jar, but as I said if I remove it from /lib or dont add the classpath entry to the manifest it doesnt even find one.

I'm on **Ubuntu 11.10**, using **Glassfish 3.1.1** and **java-6-sun-1.6.0.26** (so activation.jar is not the problem). Any idea will be much appreciated, as I can't think of anything else.

Answer (score 1):

JavaMail (all the javax.mail.* classes) is included in GlassFish (assuming you're using the full Java EE platform version and not just the Web Profile version); you shouldn't need to include mail.jar in your application or install it manually.  I can't explain why javax.mail.Message isn't found when you do that.  The ClassCastException indicates that you have two versions of mail.jar available to the application.

Comment: I found the error. The code was inside a library jar I wanted several projects to share, so I placed it in domain1/lib/ext (it wouldnt work in domain1/lib/applibs). In that library I used JDBC connection pools and other server resources and no problem, except for the email. I moved the library to domain1/lib and now my code finds javax.mail.*. I dont know if this is a strange behaviour or those folder are intended for other purposes and it was just my misunderstanding... anyway, thanks for the help, problem solved!

Comment: I think the lib/ext directory is loaded before the JDK classes and the lib directory is loaded after.